# How to optimize this sql query for faster results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a problem with some weird sql query. I'm using MySQL and i would change datatabase structure but i can't. So i have to solve my problem with query.

So i have 3 tables. Challenges, Users_challenges and Users_subscribed. What i need to get out of there 3 is the following:

I need a list of all challenges that have challenges.private = 0 and i have to exclude all challenges that appear in Users_challenges under current user id (users_challenges.iduser = 414).
Then i need challenges that can have challenges.private = 1 or 0 but they are listed in third table (users_subscribed.iduser = 414) and also here i have to exclude all read id's from the challenges table.
In the end i need to unite all the results and oreder them by time and limit.

I hope i got that correct, cuz it's pretty confusing, at least for me :D

My current query is taking 26 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM challenges
WHERE challenges.private = 0
AND challenges.isquest = 1
AND challenges.title like '%%'
AND challenges.id NOT
IN (
        SELECT users_challenges.idchallenge
        FROM users_challenges
        WHERE users_challenges.iduser = 414
        AND users_challenges.idquest IS NULL
        GROUP BY users_challenges.idchallenge
)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM challenges
WHERE challenges.isquest = 1
AND challenges.title like '%%'
AND challenges.iduser
IN (
                SELECT users_subscriptions.idsubscribedto
                FROM users_subscriptions
                WHERE users_subscriptions.iduser = 414
                UNION
                SELECT 414 AS idsubscribedto
)
AND challenges.id NOT
IN (
        SELECT users_challenges.idchallenge
        FROM users_challenges
        WHERE users_challenges.iduser
        IN (
                SELECT users_subscriptions.idsubscribedto
                FROM users_subscriptions
                WHERE users_subscriptions.iduser = 414
                UNION
                SELECT 414 AS idsubscribedto
        )
        AND users_challenges.idquest IS NULL
        GROUP BY users_challenges.idchallenge
)

ORDER BY TIME DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```

So is there a way how to simplify this query and to get same results faster?
Thx

Comment: what is the point of `AND challenges.title like '%%'`? like matches with a leading `%` disable the use of indexes.

Comment: It's because sometimes i search for title. Maybe i should exclude this line if search string is empty? Thx for info, i didnt knew that like with leading % disables the use of indexses

Answer (score 0):

If `and challenges.title like '%%'` is *not* a typo, I would remove this as a first step, because it is always true.

According to [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) it might be beneficial to use joins instead of `in (subquery)`.

You can also run the two queries separately, in order to see if just one of them is slow. Then you can focus on the slow part and leave the fast one alone.

Comment: Well it's not a typo, if search data is provided then it goes betwen wildcard characters. In php i have challenges.title line '%$search%'. Ok thx, i will try to rewrite it with joins and than see what happens.